# java linked list compare with first element and remove using peek() method

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

created java linked list to add some data. want to compare first data inside that linked list. when i use peek() it not working. any other way to get front element and compare or how to write peek() method

LinkList class :

```
package list;

public class LinkList {
    private class Node<T> {

        public final T data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void displayNode() {
            System.out.print(data + " ");
        }
    }

    public static Node first = null;
    private Node last = null;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (first == null);
    }

    public <T> void addLast(T data) {
        Node n = new Node(data);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            n.next = first;
            first = n;
            last = n;
        } else {
            last.next = n;
            last = n;
            last.next = null;
        }
    }

    public void removeFirst() {

        Node temp = first;
        if (first.next == null) {
            last = null;
        }
        first = first.next;

    }

    public void displayList() {
        Node current = first;
        while (current != null) {
            current.displayNode();
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

}
```

LinkListQueue:

```
package list;

public class LinkListQueue {
    LinkList newLinkList = new LinkList();

    public <T> void enqueue(T data) {
        newLinkList.addLast(data);

    }

    public void dequeue() {
        if (!newLinkList.isEmpty()) {
            newLinkList.removeFirst();
        }

    }

    public String displayQueue() {
        newLinkList.displayList();
        System.out.println();

        return "";
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return newLinkList.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

LinkListQueueMain :

```
package list;

public class LinkListqueueMain {
    public String getValue=null;
    public static String displayQ = null;
    static LinkListQueue queueImpl = new LinkListQueue();
    static LinkList linkList = new LinkList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runData();
    }

    public static void runData() {
        queueImpl.enqueue("80%");
        queueImpl.enqueue("70%");
        queueImpl.enqueue("60%");
        queueImpl.enqueue("85%");
        queueImpl.enqueue("45%");
        queueImpl.enqueue("55%");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(linkList.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Show what you have tried. Your question says peek is not working for you but I don't see you calling peek anywhere in your code.

Comment: And could you explain exactly what you want to do? I don't see anywhere the _peek_ function, so I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: PS (a bit unrelated): You should override the "toString" method on Node, instead of creating that function to "display node".

Comment: This code does not compile at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to paramtrize the LinkList, not necessarily the node, as the LinkList is the public API to the outer world.

```
public class LinkList<T> {
    private static class Node {
```

Then you could return the removed value. (removeFirst can throw a NullPointerException on an empty list.)

```
public T removeFirst() {
    T removed = first.data;
    if (first.next == null) {
        last = null;
    }
    first = first.next;
    return removed;
}

public T peekFirst() {
    return first.data;
}
```